# Set where the click is going to happen

Tags: javascript, jquery

html:

```
<tr id="tr">
     <td>Somthing</td>
     <td>Somthing</td>
     <td>Somthing</td>
     <td>Somthing</td>
</tr>
```

Jquery

```
$("#tr").click(function(){

// something happen

});
```

so, the question is:

the click effect obviously will get all the stuffs inside the `<tr>`

can the click effect just happen when i click in the first 3 td's inside the `<tr>` ?

**edit:**

if i have more then 1 tr

```
<tr class="tr">
     <td>Somthing</td>
     <td>Somthing</td>
     <td>Somthing</td>
     <td>Somthing</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr">
     <td>Somthing</td>
     <td>Somthing</td>
     <td>Somthing</td>
     <td>Somthing</td>
</tr>
```

the solution `td:lt(4)` will only work in the first `tr`
ps.: i neeed to identify the tr, because i have another stuffs around the code working with tr's

my real code is this:

```
$(".class td:lt(6)").live("click", function(){


 });
```

**damo:** http://jsfiddle.net/w3hKf/4/

Comment: click is an event, not effect. Also can you explain a little bit more what you need, because is not clear to me what you need.

Comment: @Sotiris: yes, effect that i mean is the "event of click"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the [lt (less than) selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/).

```
$('.specialTD td:lt(4)').click(function(){

// what cell was clicked?
var clickedId = $(this).attr('id');

});
```

UPDATE:

You can assign a class name that will be same on all rows, and an individual id to each td. See updated example above

Comment: +1 I learn something new every day.  Except it is 0 based, so it should be :lt(3)

Comment: why when i have more then 1 tr , the second one dos not mande the click event ? just the first one go's

Comment: Because we are selecting by your row id of "tr".  Use $('tr td:lt(3)') instead. Notice the missing "#".

Comment: @John Strickler: yes, aready change the id for a class, because i need to identify where i'm clicking in that case

Comment: id's are supposed to be used only once, it's better if you set a class name to  all the tr tags on the table you want this behavior on, then do:  

$('.classname td:lt(4)').click(function(){
// something happen
});

See [this page for explanation](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/cssid.php)

Answer (score 0):

you can bind the event handler to the third element only like this:

```
$("#tr td:eq(2)").click(function(){

// somthing happen

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!

### [JSfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/KHybt/4/)

```
//########## using :lt() selector

$('#test1 li:lt(3)').css({color: '#cf5'});

$('#test1 li:lt(3)').click(function() {
    $(this).css({color: '#caf'});
});

//########## using .slice() method for better performance

$('#test2 li').slice(0, 3).css({color: '#cf5'});

$('#test2 li').click(function() {
    $(this).slice(0, 3).css({color: '#caf'});
});
```

*"Because :lt() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :lt() cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use $("your-pure-css-selector").slice(0, index) instead."* (jQuery.com)

DOCUMENTATION:
http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/
http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("tr#tr td:not(:last)").click(function(){

// somthing happen

});
```